# Update WebView using Thread/Task

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, webview, javafx-2

I am trying to update a WebView in my GUI using JavaFx. Actually, I want to load a (local) html file to the WebView when my task (takes a bit) ends. My controller class is below.

```
@FXML
private WebView bubbleChart;
//...

@FXML
private void startAnalysis(ActionEvent event) {
     Task<Void> topicAnalysis = new MyTrendAnalysis();
     Platform.runLater(topicAnalysis);
   //Thread t = new Thread(topicAnalysis);
   //t.setDaemon(true);
   //t.start();
}
```

In my Task class there is a method that changes the html file for the WebView.

```
private class MyTrendAnalysis extends TrendAnalysis{

    // some other stuff

    @Override
    public void drawResults() {
        try {
            bubbleChart.getEngine().load(new File("path").toURI().toURL().toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TabPaneController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

When I use the `Platform.runLater();` command my app go unresponding until Task is finished. In the end updates the webview, like it is supposed to.
When i try *Thread-way* (code in comments) I'm able to interact with the app (e.g. change tabs, etc) but in the end WebView is not updated and I got :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-8
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:238)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:238)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:400)
>       at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.checkThread(WebEngine.java:931)
>       at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.load(WebEngine.java:723)
>       at prototype.TabPaneController$MyTrendAnalysis.drawResults(TabPaneController.java:233)
>       at prototype.TopicAnalysis.TrendAnalysis.call(TrendAnalysis.java:342)
>       at prototype.TopicAnalysis.TrendAnalysis.call(TrendAnalysis.java:33)
>       at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1259)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

There is any way to get a responding behavior and my WebView updated?

Comment: Run it in a separate thread but call `bubbleChart.getEngine().load(new File("path").toURI().toURL().toString());` with `Platform.runLater()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It took me while, but I got it!